# Calculating the slope for all points in a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

My input is a matrix where every value represents the elevation of that point of a topographical map.  I need to calculate the direction of downhill for every point. From my research, the gradient descent will essentially give me this value, but from what I can see, I need the function that defines the elevation so that I can find the partial derivatives, but obviously I don't have the function.

I am a novice, but it seems I could use Machine Learning to estimate the function and then calculate the gradient from the defined coefficients.

Ultimately, I am looking for an algorithm to find the direction of the steepest descent for each point in this topographical map.

Comment: Use finite-differences, not differentials.

Comment: Are the points for which you have data arranged in a grid? Are you interested in the directions of steepest descent for points not in your data set?  Are the elevations accurate?

Comment: If the values are arranged as a grid you should look up the Sobel or Richards gradient estimators.